# "I'm interested in you" -- Is this sentence in a passive form?

Tags: passive-voice, deverbal

> I'm not interested in you.
>
> I'm interested in you.

Is this in passive form?  If not, please explain to me what structure it is following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can view it as a passive form of the sentence *You interest me.* However, the proper passive form of this sentence is *I'm interested **by** you*.

On the other hand, you can say that *interested* is an adjective and that *interested in sb.* is an adjective (deverbal) phrase.

So yes, you can view it as a sentence in passive voice, but if you wish, you can view it as a descriptive sentence that says: *I'm a person with a specific property: interest in you.* Since the proposition has changed and since the "passive" form is more common than the "active" form of this statement, I would be inclined to the latter explanation.

Comment: I can't see any passive here. "I'm interested in you" is to  be + an adjective  in the form of a past participle.  The sentence  does not describe an action the subject "I"  receives, but a state.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of passive voice: be+past participle. However, your sentence is something different. It says: be+adjective.

Take a look at the following examples:

I am happy (=adjective) with you. (Active sentence)
I am interested (=adjective) in you. (Active sentence)

However, "I am interested (=past participle) by her" is an incorrect sentence.